# How can I prevent my phone from using any kind of internet?

Tags: 3g, data-connection, wi-fi

I have a weird plan and my phone went over its bandwidth usage this month... mostly just syncing up with Gmail, Twitter etc. So right now, every 5 minutes or so, my phone is telling me that it has spent 40 cents here and 30 cents there using up my prepaid money.

I have done the following:

- Turned off Wifi (my phone doesn't see any WiFi spots anyway right now)
- Turned off all apps
- Turned off syncing of data

However its still dinging me here and there and I need my phone minutes to last until it automatically reloads in two days. I've noticed that I will kill certain apps and then I find out they are turned back on... and syncing even though I told the phone not to.

Short of putting the phone on airplane mode (which I don't want to do because I'm expecting an important phone call - also my phone then becomes totally useless.), I can't seem to keep it from using the 3G network!

Comment: n.b. many phones in airplane mode will momentarily connect to cellular at boot time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just kill the APN Connection settings. Somewhere under settings. And there is actually a switch for mobile internet. Disable that as well. Worked like a charm for me. If you can't find it, add the Power Savings widget to your home screen, it has that option

Comment: looking up the exact settings, give me a minute :)

Comment: I think that worked. The 3g symbol is gone! :)

Answer (score 5):

On my Galaxy S, you can hold the power button for a second and a menu will come up.  Just hit "Data network mode" to deactivate it.  You can reactivate it the same way.

If you don't have that, you should be able to go to `Settings -> Wireless and network -> Mobile networks` and uncheck **Data enabled** or **Use packet data** or similar.

Comment: The Incredible has this feature as well.

Answer (score 4):

I use [APNDroid](http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/) (Also available in the marketplace for free). You can easily turn data on or off with the press of a button.

Add the APNDroid widget to your home screen to easily turn data on or off.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use data some of the time (sounds like you might if you're running a twitter app), I'd second Jonathan's plug for APNdroid.

Once you've installed it, longpress on your screen and select "widgets" to place the APNdroid widget on your home screen, and you can turn data on and off. The other really handy widget is "Power Control" which is nominally there to give you control over your power consumption but functionally lets you turn bluetooth, wifi, GPS and background syncing on and off.

Wifi shouldn't be using your minutes at all, though. You should be able to use it instead of the 3G network.

Comment: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.code.apndroid&feature=search_result